# Why can't I spoof my ip address and trick the Marklogic function 'xdmp:get-request-client-address' to think I'm somewhere else in the world?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I've tried using an `x-forwarded-for` header with IP addresses from Mexico, London, etc... I've used the google sensor tool to change my IP but Marklogic somehow sees through those techniques when I log the results of this function  `xdmp:get-request-client-address`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`xdmp:get-request-client-address()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:get-request-client-address) returns

> the internet address of the client from which the HTTP server request
>   is issued

If you want the value of the `x-forwarded-for` header, then use [`xdmp:get-request-header()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:get-request-header). You can use the request client address as a default value in case that header is not found:

```
xdmp:get-request-header("x-forwarded-for", xdmp:get-request-client-address())
```

Comment: I haven't studied the x-forwarded-for header much. Is it common that most users visiting a site will have that header? I'm trying to get the ip address of users visiting our site so we can see which country they're coming from but I'm only doing it for users in countries speaking spanish so I am trying to test it by spoofing my ip to be one of the IPs in a spanish speaking country but Marklogic always seems to find my correct ip.